# Laravel Eloquent One-to-One produces extra queries when referencing relation from the other

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models that are setup in a one to one relation. In one of the models I reference another field from another model through a mutator/accessor. I fetch the relationship using with. When I convert the data to array then it produces an extra query.

Left.php

```
class Left extends Model
{
...
    public function right()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Right::class);
    }
...
```

Right.php

```
class Right extends Model
...
    public function left()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Left::class);
    }
...
    public function getSomeFieldAttribute()
    {
        return $this->left->someField;
    }
...
```

Fetch the data like so:

```
$lefts = Left::with(['right'])->get();
// convert to array
$lefts->toArray();
```

The line `$lefts = Left::with(['right'])->get();` produces two queries, but when calling `$lefts->toArray()` it'll produce additional queries to retrieve `$this->left` within each `Right`. Is it possible to use the data from `$lefts = Left::with(['right'])->get();` rather than produces those extra queries?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not possible with Laravel on its own. I think you'd have to code that yourself (something like `$left->right->setAttribute('some_field', $left->some_field)`).

Comment: I didn't think so. Is it possible to set the entire relation rather than individual fields?

Comment: Judging by [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L702) you could do `$left->setRelation('right', $right)`. Never tried it though.

Comment: @devk that worked. Don't like that I have to loop through and add the relationship but it saves some queries. Thanks!

Comment: If you eager load the relation, you have just one extra query: `Left::with(['right.left'])->get();`